# Can't find range of files by bash

Tags: bash

I've got a case to remove all the **file-names** which is:

1) not in range **1-8192**

2) not **64 characters(SHA-256)** filenames

3) In template of **FTP_{32characters}{32spaces}**

in the directories **./0*/storage*/** but I can't find resolving.

```
find ./0*/storage*/ -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name '*[[:digit:]]' -a ! -name 'Uploads'
```

doesn't do it fully because it finds filenames with at least one number.
Do you have some hints?
Thank you.

Comment: This question isn't very clear. Are you attempting to list all files *except* those which match any of those rules?